# prove M is End(M)-left module

Tags: modules

I have module theory mid-term exam and I studied on modules over the ring I solve many questions but I reached my main problem is to prove the well-definition. in this question, the goal is proving  M is End(M)-left module, I proved End(M) is a ring and M is an abelian group so just remind to **prove well-definition** of map from End(M)*M to M st. for all f in End(M) and for all m in M, fm=f(m), is there any fixed solution of proving well defined?

End(M) is a set of all M to M homomorphisms

Comment: "proveign well defined" proving _what_ is well-defined?   That's the real question. I'm not even sure you know what has to be well-defined, yet.  The answer, of course, is the proposed action of $End(M)$ on $M$. Fortunately there is a very natural one, and I don't think there is anything problematic about proving it is well-defined...

Comment: yes you are right I have a basic problem, but it's problematic for me because I couldn't find a fix approach for it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proving that $M$ is a well-defined $\mathrm{End}(M)$-module really only requires defining the action. How does $\mathrm{End}(M)$ act on $M$? And does it satisfy the axioms of a module action?
$$
f.(m+n) = f.m+f.n
\\
(f+g).m = f.m + g.m
\\
(fg).m = f.(g.m) 
$$

---

For contrast, **a case where you might need to do more work to prove an action is well-defined is if you're dealing with a quotient**. For example, suppose that $N$ is a submodule of $M$, regarding both as left $M$-modules. Then the quotient $M/N$ is a left $M$-module too: for $\overline{x} \in M/N$ you define the action as $m.\overline{x} = \overline{m.x}$. *But this choice depends on the representative $x \in M$ you chose of the element in the quotient $\overline{x} \in M/N$*. Does this definition of the action still work if you pick a different representative? I.e. if $\overline{x} = \overline{y}$, then does $\overline{m.x} = \overline{m.y}$? In this case, asking if the action is "well-defined" is more meaningful.